# Macro Economic Factors that Effect the Revenue for General Mills

Tags: macroeconomics, open-economy-macro

I was having a conversation with a friend about politics, and that eventually led to economics. I know... We're a little on the wild side. He made a comment that he thinks that a company like General Mills (there happened to be a box of my kids Cheerios on the table) should be able to be profitable as long as they have a good product and business plan. I agreed to a point, but remembering back to my economics classes from years ago , I said that macro economic factors also have a big impact on a company's revenue. For the sake of my argument I tried to think of some examples, but for the life of me I couldn't think of any good ones. All I could think of was average annual household income, but I'm really not sure what kind of an effect that has on a company like General Mills. On one hand I can see how it would give people less money to buy the product, but on the other hand maybe it causes people to buy more of their products because they don't have as much money to eat out all the time. Anyway, It really hurt my debate score, and more importantly, it just really bothers me not knowing the answer to something. That's why I came here for advice. I don't necessarily need 5, I just thought having a few would really solidify my point and it said to be specific with my question.

Comment: That reads like a homework. If that's one, would you care to tell us how far you've been? Homeworks questions are accepted on the site, but only if you've shown that you've spend a reasonable effort trying to answer it.

Comment: No, it's not homework. I finished school about 12 years ago. That's why I don't remember much from my Economic classes! I just edited the question to better explain why I'm looking for this answer. Thanks.